# Postgres: pass schema as variable to a function with trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-schema

I'd pass as variable the schema name in a function with trigger

Function and trigger are so defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $shp_create$

  BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'NEW: %', NEW;
    IF NEW.log_type = false THEN

        INSERT INTO target_table
        SELECT * FROM $%%NEW.schema_or%%%.start_table 
    
        NEW.log_type := true;

      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;

 $test$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_trigger ON table_log;
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table_log
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();
```

table_log is so defined:

```
log_type|schema_or
--------|---------
 false    test
```

So the Insert statment in the function become:

```
INSERT INTO target_table
SELECT * FROM test.start_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO target_table
        SELECT * FROM %I.start_table', NEW.schema_or )
```

This use the string function [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to create a query string that can then be executed. Look at the `format` link for a full explanation of what is possible. In this case `%I` refers to an identifier, the schema name.

Comment: Not sure why: `format('INSERT INTO target_table SELECT string_agg(field::varchar,''-'') FROM %I.start_table', 'test' );` yielding: `INSERT INTO target_table SELECT string_agg(field::varchar,'-') FROM test.start_table` would not work? What is the error you get?